# Anonymous type dynamic object error cant implicitly convert string to int

Tags: c#, asp.net, deserialization

In order to make sortable an asp grid bound to an linq result set at runtime with dynamic fields (so I can't create template fields) I decided to try serializing the table's results and putting it in a viewstate to be called, de serialized, ordered and rebound on the gridview's sorting event.

Unfortunately the assigning to a new type after the fact gives the error  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int', but I cant work out why/where it would be trying to do this.

The code up to the point of failure is:

```
         string sSData = (string)ViewState["resultData"];
         JavaScriptSerializer jSS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
         dynamic dynObject = jSS.DeserializeObject(sSData);


         var resultsdDS = new 
         {
             Student_Forename = dynObject["Student_Forename"],
             Student_Surname = dynObject["Student_Surname"]
         };
```

There is the correct datatypes in the dynObject (some are ints), but not in the selected fields though the error indicates its trying to turn a string to an int, not vice versa (and these fields arent assigned anyway in this test)

Anything to help me understand what's going on would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the value of `sSData` after you cast it to a string? It might help to see the view as well.

Comment: I worked out what was going on, in that dynObject is an object containing n rows of 10 sets of key/value pairs, and what dynObject["Student_Forename"] was trying to do was pull the entire 10 key value set for the row (hence why it was complaining about casting an int to a string, as there's no row number "Student_Forename"

What I actually wanted to do was pull certain key/value pairs from each row, but i'm still working out if this is possible without a for/each